# how to use the camera roll feature which says upload video to youtube, email and mms, in our own iphone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have built an iphone application which makes a video and than you can record the video further. now the main part or my application is that i want to upload it to youtube or e-mail it. now conventionally you take a video or picture for instance from the gallery and using the camera roll feature.
can i utilize that feature in my own application so that after i have recorded a video through my iphone application i dont have to go back to the camera roll feature which is there in the iphone built in gallery.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can get access to those features within your app.

You'll have to implement these features yourself.

Comment: thank you very much for ur comment to my query, now can u help me out with some tutorial or reading stuff so it might help me in dealing with my problem...

Comment: There's a multitude of things you'll need to look at. Apple has an extensive collection of documentation and sample code at http://developer.apple.com/iphone You could probably pick up a book or two as well, perhaps iPhone Developer Cookbook by Erica Sadun or iPhone SDK Developement by Bill Dudney.